# The deliver function on every Token out there

Tags: erc-20

```
    function deliver(uint256 tAmount) public {
        address sender = _msgSender();
        require(!_isExcluded[sender], "Excluded addresses cannot call this function");
        (uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
        _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
        _rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rAmount);
        _tFeeTotal = _tFeeTotal.add(tAmount);
    }
```

On every possible token publish today coping Safemoon reflection method, there is a deliver function that is not called anywhere in the code, does anyone knows its purpose?

Comment: I'm new to solidity dev, but I've studied these contracts, and personally I think it can safely be removed if you have no use for it (and I imagine most wouldn't). 

It's not part of the ERC-20/BEP-20 standard and there is nowhere it's called in the contract itself. 

On Certik's Safemoon audit, they also mentioned they had no idea why it was there.

Comment: That would only marginally reduce deployment cost and i think its a good feature to keep

Answer (score 2):

This is a wild guess but from the little understanding i have of safemoon contract this looks like it allows a user (not excluded from fees) to give away `tAmount` of tokens as reflections.

Edit : yeah actually maybe someone can confirm but im almost 100% sure thats it

Comment: I actually think the same, I just wanted to confirm it and to see that there is no hidden reason behind it

Answer (score 1):

`deliver(uint256 tAmount)` allows a 'standard'/non-excluded from reflection address to reduce its reflected token amount in order to increase all the others non-excluded addresses balances (via the elastic supply ratio).

The second to last line in deliver `_rTotal = _rTotal.sub(rAmount);` means the "total amount of reflection" decreases by the equivalent of amount in reflected token. This increases the ratio 'token/reflected token' that is used to computed any user balance:

Balance of non-excluded is based on tokenFromReflection of the number of reflected tokenowned:

```
function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
  if (_isExcluded[account]) return _tOwned[account];
  return tokenFromReflection(_rOwned[account]);
}
```

Which is the the number of reflected tokens owned divided by the current rate:

```
function tokenFromReflection(uint256 rAmount) public view returns(uint256) {
    require(rAmount <= _rTotal, "Amount must be less than total reflections");
    uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
    return rAmount.div(currentRate);
}
```

And the current rate is (total of reflected token) / (total of token) :

```
function _getRate() private view returns(uint256) {
    (uint256 rSupply, uint256 tSupply) = _getCurrentSupply();
    return rSupply.div(tSupply);
}

function _getCurrentSupply() private view returns(uint256, uint256) {
    uint256 rSupply = _rTotal;
    uint256 tSupply = _tTotal;      
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _excluded.length; i++) {
        if (_rOwned[_excluded[i]] > rSupply || _tOwned[_excluded[i]] > tSupply) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
        rSupply = rSupply.sub(_rOwned[_excluded[i]]);
        tSupply = tSupply.sub(_tOwned[_excluded[i]]);
    }
    if (rSupply < _rTotal.div(_tTotal)) return (_rTotal, _tTotal);
    return (rSupply, tSupply);
}
```

The increase of total fee paid looks rather like a way to to account for it, without effect on other parameters of the token.